Computational advantage with cNOT+Toffoli+ $|0\rangle, |+\rangle$ state preparation
Are there proofs (under complexity theoretic conjectures) indicating that a computational advantage can be obtained in presence of cNOT and Toffoli gate only (assuming one can prepare or measure qubits in single-qubit Pauli eigenstates).
Naïvely it could be possible because the set is composed of cNOT+one non-Clifford gate (Toffoli) and we can initialize qubits in a superposition state, but it could also be too restrictive.

If you can prepare Pauli eigenstates and have CNOT and classical feedback then you can do Hadamard gates by teleportation. Which gives you Toffoli+H, which is BQP complete, so this gateset is BQP complete.
Here is the Hadamard circuit (the H+measure is an x basis measurement):


Neat. Can this be formalized why this works, or better which gates can be implemented in such a setting (e.g. certain stabilizer operations + states + measurements)?

Thanks. Do you have a reference in a paper that mentions this circuit (or a similar one that can inject $H$ given my constraints)? Or maybe you simply found this circuit yourself?

@MarcoFellous-Asiani I made it to answer your question.

@NorbertSchuch It's three S gate teleportations driven by S|+> states, with the middle one applied to the X axis instead of the Z axis, giving sqrt(Z)*sqrt(X)sqrt(Z) = Hpaulis.

Unmagic gate teleportation!
